# Draw a circle backwards in Python Turtle

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics

I need to draw a circle bit instead of going clockwise, go anticlockwise when drawing. I need it to go back about the same distance it went forward. (look in code)

Ive tried the command "circle(100, 30)"

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Pen()
t.speed(0)
def drawKrusty(size):
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(size)
    t.left(90)
    t.fillcolor("grey")
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        t.forward(size / 10)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(size)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(size / 20)
    t.circle(size, 30)
    t.backcircle(size, 60)
    t.end_fill()
drawKrusty(500)
```

Comment: `. Draw the arc in counterclockwise direction if radius is positive, otherwise in clockwise direction. ` (from https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) So try `t.circle(-100, 30)` or something?

Comment: @h4z3, right idea, wrong argument.  By replacing `t.backcircle(size, 60)` with `t.circle(-size, 60)` you start a completely new clockwise arc from the current point in the current heading, which doesn't trace over the old arc.  (Did you test this?)  @Tobbor's answer of `t.circle(size, -60)` is correct.

Comment: @cdlane I only quoted the docs - they said about changing the radius. It was a quick comment and I didn't claim I was correct - it's just a comment, not an answer, just a quick pointer with "try ... or something". I just believe many things can be solved by reading the docs. ;) + If you rotate the pen, -radius or -angle becomes the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the `extent` (the second) parameter of `circle` to negative value - arc will go in the counterclockwise direction. `t.circle(size, -60)`

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted, this is the correct answer (+1).  Replace `t.backcircle(size, 60)` with `t.circle(size, -60)` and it will trace over the existing `t.circle(size, 30)` and continue to draw the matching arc in the other direction.